# Implement Pandora channel as background music on my website. Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pandora

I'd like to add the free version of Pandora to my website as background music. I'm not sure if this is possible. I can't find any information on this integration.

I'm assuming since anyone can freely listen to Pandora with commercials it would be fine to have a background music.

I would also need to be able to select which channel to play, may also need to have a play/stop button too, but that can be figured out later.

Any ideas from anyone on how to implement something like this using Jquery preferably or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to add the free version of Pandora to my website as background music. I'm not sure if this is possible.

Not possible. Pandora has never supported this; it's likely that their license agreements for music usage wouldn't permit it.

Answer (score 1):

Pandora has a new [Developer Center](https://developer.pandora.com/), but access to the API is restricted (approval required) and website integrations in particular cannot be approved at the moment due to some limitations in our public API. We are working on filling this gap.